# $8\sin x\cos x-\sqrt{6} \sin x- \sqrt{6} \cos x+1=0$, Solve for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, quadratics, substitution

> Solve for $x:0\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$
>
> $$8\sin x\cos x-\sqrt{6} \sin x- \sqrt{6} \cos x+1=0$$

My attempt,

I changed it into $$1+4 \sin 2x-2\sqrt{3} \sin (x+\frac{\pi}{4})=0$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\sin{x}+\cos{x}=t$ and we get a quadratic equation:
$$4(t^2-1)-\sqrt6t+1=0.$$

Comment: squaring is not so good, you can get additionally solutions

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner It's just substitution! $\sin{x}\cos{x}=\frac{t^2-1}{2}$.

Comment: hello, Michael, i have told you already, my Name is Sonnhard.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, Squaring would have been $$(8\sin x\cos x+1)^2=(\sqrt6\cos x+\sqrt6\sin x)^2=6(1+2\sin x\cos x)$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: use the substituion
$$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$
$$\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
where $$\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=t$$
then you will have
$$\frac{16t(1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)^2}-\frac{2\sqrt{6}t}{1+t^2}-\sqrt{6}\frac{(1-t^2)}{1+t^2}+1=0$$

Comment: How have you solved the horrible bi-quadratic equation?

Comment: i hae got this here $$ \left( \sqrt {6}+1 \right)  \left( 2\,\sqrt {6}t-{t}^{2}+2\,\sqrt {6}
-4\,t-5 \right)  \left( 4\,\sqrt {6}t-5\,{t}^{2}+4\,\sqrt {6}+16\,t+11
 \right) 
=0$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $t=\sin x+ \cos x$ and use $1=\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of Michael Rozenberg's answer,

$$\cos x+\sin x=\sqrt2\cos\left(\dfrac\pi4-x\right)$$

Set $\dfrac\pi4-x=y\iff x=?$

$2\sin x\cos x=\sin2x=\sin2\left(\dfrac\pi4-y\right)=\cos2y=2\cos^2y-1$

So, we have $$0=4(2\cos^2y-1)-2\sqrt3\cos y+1=8\cos^2y-2\sqrt3\cos y-3$$ which is a quadratic equation in $\cos y$